# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity and Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to publish a test website from the new `Visual Studio 2013 RC` to azure using the `MVC 5 spa template`.

I can get the register / log in / log off process working just fine except there's a small issue that's bothering me. If I try to log in using bad credentials, the error string that comes back to the page is "An unknown error occurred." instead of "The user name or password is incorrect." as it should if `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` in `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs` is working properly.

On localhost, I get back the correct "The user name or password is incorrect." message.

Error log from Azure:

```
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<h3>HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request</h3> 
<h4>Bad Request</h4> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4> 
<ul>    <li></li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 
<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4> 
<ul>    <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
<div id="details-left"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;__DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_08fdea3d-9972-4dc2-b0fc-c8ffdb2e4253</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AuthenticateRequest</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr> 

</table> 
</div> 
<div id="details-right"> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://[site]:80/Token</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\DWASFiles\Sites\[site]\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\Token</td></tr> 
<tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Not yet determined</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Not yet determined</td></tr> 

</table> 
<div class="clear"></div> 
</div> 
</fieldset> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
<fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> 
The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. 
<p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=400,0,0x00000000,9200">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 
<p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p>
```

I'm not sure how it could be malformed syntax since the same syntax is sent and processed when correct login credentials are submitted.

Does anyone have enough familiarity with this to know what's going on, or at least a path to go down to get closer to an answer other than the knowledge base article? If it's not obvious already, I'm new to this - it's my first website in ASP.NET, first introduction to OAuth, and first use of Azure.

Comment: I've been looking at the POST headers and request body in fiddler and I can't see any difference between the syntax of a login with good credentials and one with bad credentials. Is anyone else having this issue? Perhaps it's some bug associated with the fact that this is the new mvc 5 identity system? Maybe the azure log that suggests the problem is malformed syntax is wrong.

Comment: It seems that is not a Azure problem, but ASP.NET MVC. Maybe in your code, you will display the name of the user, but you're not checking if the Identity is different than null value. A good tip: Enable Nugget Elmah and repeat this test. You'll be able to see the error and stacktrace.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the code is working on localhost. It only returns 'An unknown error has occurred." on Azure. I just updated the original post to indicate this. I will look into Elmah though, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this has been viewed a few times I just wanted to add an update/answer. I never did find out what the problem was, but it went away after updating to Visual Studio 2013 RTM. There were quite a few updates to ASP.Identity in the RTM so I'm not sure what fixed it (it may even have been unrelated to VS and got fixed by an update that got applied to Azure for all I know), but hopefully anyone who had this same problem has also seen it go away.